# Arduino UNO HTTPS

Tags: arduino-uno

Is it possible to call a HTTPS web service on arduino UNO? I am trying to connect it through client.connect(ip,port). It said connected but never respond, ended up in TIMEOUT.

Comment: You have some sort of Ethernet or WIFI interface don't you, which one?

Comment: ethernet shield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The Arduino UNO is not powerful enough to encrypt the data for an SSL connection. On top of that the W5100 chip used on the Ethernet shield has its own IP stack built into it, and that stack doesn't support SSL either.

If you require SSL then it is recommended that you use one of the "dual" boards, like the Yun, and have the Linux portion of the board make the SSL connection for you using cURL.